# How to export Wordpress posts including the User Access of each post?

Tags: wordpress

The Wordpress is using **User Access Manager** plugin.

I've tried to export the posts from Admin Tools. However, the exported posts don't include the User Access.

Comment: what is your ultimate goal? you want to migrate your installation? please also take the [tour] ans look at [ask]

Comment: I will migrate the exported data (post content and user access) to non-Wordpress (SharePoint)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up by directly get the data from the database:

1. Execute a Query in the database
2. Export the Query result into csv
3. Run a PowerShell migration script to upload each posts in the csv into a SharePoint list.